# game ranking position

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a list of players in a game with a highscore. I want to get my score if my name is "jimbo" and get my ranking position and the people who are the next to me in the ranking, 2 places better and 2 places worse.

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playername` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `highscore` bigint(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=106 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is through the use of a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ranked_players AS
SELECT id, playername, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rank
FROM players
JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS RANK
ORDER BY highscore DESC;
```

You might want to add `id` or `playername` if you want to ensure a consistent ordering of players with the same `highscore`.

Now you'll need to figure out the rank for the player (note that MySQL will not allow you to use the temporary table twice in the same query, hence this cannot be put in a subquery of the next statement):

```
SELECT rank
INTO @myrank
FROM ranked_players
WHERE playername = 'jimbo';
```

Then you'll want to get the range of players with a rank from 2 places up to 2 places down:

```
SELECT players.*
FROM players
JOIN ranked_players USING (id)
WHERE rank BETWEEN (@myrank - 2) AND (@myrank + 2)
ORDER BY highscore DESC;
```

Then you cleanup the temporary table:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE ranked_players;
```

Finally, you can reduce this to a single query if you pre-compute the list of users with the `rank` in an actual table that you'll refresh whenever it makes sense to your application (I suppose it's a compromise between performance and real-time-ness). The query you'd then use can be easily derived form the above ones, with the difference that you're not limited by the restrictions of temporary tables I mentioned.